# Loading & executing audio.js on jQueryMobile AJAX page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a page that is being displayed via jQuery Mobile which has an audio.js player on it.

However, when the page is loaded via jQuery Mobile's AJAX hijacking of the click handler, then the audio.js code doesn't get executed so there is no audio player.

Is there a way that I can get Javascript code, such as the audio.js code, to execute when the pages are being loaded via AJAX?

You can see an example of the issue by going to http://media.urbansermons.net/m/audio-list/term/6711 and then clicking on any of the audios listed there. Note that this is a test site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user has to click on an item, if instead of loading a new link in the browser you made the switch from list to detail page using DIVs so no opening a new URL you could use the same click to start the player (since mobile devices makes it necessary that a click event precedes the play of audio/video.

Also on the link you sent all the mp3 come back as empty files.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at this, but the CMS that I am using makes this difficult.